# Maximum loading volume for agarose gel with 10 well comb

Tags: pcr, cloning

I want to load my agarose gel with my PCR products, which are 50 µL reactions.

I am wondering how much of those reaction I can load into one well if I use a standard agarose mini gel (10 well comb, ~8 mm thickness, 1.2%).

Should I try loading the entire 50 µL into one well or should I split it into two?

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: Why do you want to load so much sample?

Comment: Low concentration or for gel extraction I would assume...

Comment: Yeah, it is for gel extraction. I want to load maximum sample while using the minimal amount of gels

Comment: If this is for gel extraction, load two lanes. Or connect two on the comb with tape to make a bigger well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many samples have you got? You can tape neighbouring teeth of the comb together to create double- or triple-wide wells to load more sample.

I don't normally load more that about 20 µL.

You could also make the gel thicker potentially.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, I only have one standard agarose apparatus, and it doesn't allow me to use wider gels. I tested with loading buffer in one well, whether or not it would fit 50 µL. It did, but I didn't take the risk of losing sample due to leakage, so I will just run more gels. Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: @Philz0rs If this answer [addressed your problem](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.